# REST urls with tastypie

Tags: django, rest, tastypie

I'm using tastypie in my django application and I'm trying to get it to map urls like "/api/booking/2011/01/01" which maps to a Booking model with the specified timestamp in the url. The documentation falls short of telling how to achieve this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you want to do in your Resource is provide an

```
def prepend_urls(self):
    return [
        url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<year>[\d]{4})/(?P<month>{1,2})/(?<day>[\d]{1,2})%s$" % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('dispatch_list_with_date'), name="api_dispatch_list_with_date"),
    ]
```

method, which returns a url, which points to a view (I named it dispatch_list_with_date) that does what you want.

For example, in the base_urls class, it points to a view called 'dispatch_list' that's the primary entry point for listing a resource, and you'll probably just want to sort of replicate that with your own filtering.

Your view might look pretty similar to this

```
def dispatch_list_with_date(self, request, resource_name, year, month, day):
    # dispatch_list accepts kwargs (model_date_field should be replaced) which 
    # then get passed as filters, eventually, to obj_get_list, it's all in this file
    # https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py
    return dispatch_list(self, request, resource_name, model_date_field="%s-%s-%s" % year, month, day)
```

Really I would probably just add a [filter](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#basic-filtering) to the normal list resource

```
GET /api/booking/?model_date_field=2011-01-01
```

You can get this by adding a filtering attribute to your Meta class

But that's a personal preference.

Comment: ah okay, so I reckon it's probably better not to use tastypie at all if I want to achieve the former. since I could implement it with vanilla django's url_conf anyways.

Comment: I'm pretty partial to the extra functionality, and the formatting of Tastypie, but sure, always more than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: Comment in tastypie code: override_urls is deprecated. Will be removed by v1.0.0. Please use ``prepend_urls`` instead.

Comment: Yeah, soon you'll have to use prepend_urls. Updated response.